# Sequelize automatically adds colums

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

[Model].findOne({}) throws unknown colum error, but i dont have that column in my model, but it adds the colum modifieddate and updatedat and somecolum while fineOne runs

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `timestamp:false` in the options where you are defining the model.

For example:

```
var Bar = sequelize.define('Bar', { }, {
  timestamps: false,
})
```

For reference check this [Sequelize model definition](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-definition/#configuration)